# Changing buffer units in Python script

Tags: python, buffer

If I use the standard buffer tool in ArcMap, I can set the units for the buffers. I'm trying to execute a python script to do the same thing, but the resulting buffers are huge and incorrect, indicating that the units are wrong. Is there a good way to set the units in the script, or is this just the result of the projection I'm using? My data is all being projected into a state plane system using feet, but the feature I'm trying to buffer is in WGS 1984 (degrees).

I tried to research a bit but didn't find much.

```
#assign variable bus routes
routes = r"C:\Users\bobby\Desktop\gis data\Bus redesign.gdb\BusRoutes"
buffDists = [300, 600, 900]
#create arcpybuffer

for buff in buffDists:
    arcpy.Buffer_analysis(routes, routes + str(buff), buff)
    print (str(buff) + " is processing")

print("script complete")
```

Comment: If you follow the documented parameter list, you could add the units to the distance and specify that a GEODESIC calculation is needed.  `...,"{:d} feet".format(buff),method='GEODESIC')`

Comment: Could you please confirm that `routes` is in a projected coordinate system, rather than a geographic coordinate system?

Comment: @Aaron, it's not, and maybe that's the issue. I know how to project it into the data frame as state plane but not how to change the coordinate system that came with the data..

Comment: @Vince that was super helpful and seemed to work but adding the change seemed to cause WinPy to hang and not respond. If I shut it down and check the output geodatabase, 2 out of the three buffer distances are there. Any advice?

Comment: As long as the data is in a projected coordinate system, you will not have issues with the buffer distances.